# Get IStructuredSelection Name

Tags: java, treeview, jface, selectionchanged

I am using tree viewer to display a list of elements on the selection changed listener I want to get the name of the selected node. Here is my selection listener

```
 treeViewerSwaComponents.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {

            IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();

            if (sel.isEmpty())
                return;

            Component component = (Component) sel.getFirstElement();
            notifyComponentSelection(component);
        }

    });
```

How can I get the name of the selected node as a string.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'name'? Do you mean the text returned by the label provider?

Comment: yes the text returned by label provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your label provider implements `ILabelProvider` you can use:

```
ILabelProvider provider = (ILabelProvider)treeViewerSwaComponents.getLabelProvider();

String name = provider.getText(sel.getFirstElement());
```

Comment: I want to get the text of the label before I cast it to component Object because on the basis of the text of label I will decide if I have to cast it or not